# WordPress sort posts according to data in another db

Tags: database, wordpress

We could use WP_Query to sort posts by meta_value in WordPress DB. I'd like to sort posts by page view. However, I have stored the post page view in another database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/federated-storage-engine.html

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL database without using replication or cluster technology.
>   Querying a local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the
>   remote (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.
>
> To include the FEDERATED storage engine if you build MySQL from
>   source, invoke CMake with the -DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE option.
>
> The FEDERATED storage engine is not enabled by default in the running
>   server; to enable FEDERATED, you must start the MySQL server binary
>   using the --federated option.
>
> To examine the source for the FEDERATED engine, look in the
>   storage/federated directory of a MySQL source distribution.